# Web Audio Constructors and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, audio

I'm trying to figure out a way to have cleaner, efficient code for a web audio project i've been working on. the code I have right now is this:

```
//OSCILLATOR INFO//
// Oscillator Pitch is in Hz.
// Oscillator Detune is in Cents & can be positive or negative values. 
// 1 Octave = double/half the note frequency in Hz. (A3 = 220Hz; A4 = 440Hz; A5 = 880Hz)
// 1 Octave = 1200 Cents. 100 Cents per Semitone. (A3 - A4 = 1200 Cents; A4 - A5 = 1200 Cents)
// 12 Semitones per Octave.
// (A-440Hz detuned by 100 cents = A#; detuned by -100 cents = Ab)
//JQUERY SET UP//
//WEB AUDIO SET UP//
//used start web audio
var ctx = new webkitAudioContext();
speakers = ctx.destination;
var osc1 = ctx.createOscillator();
var osc2 = ctx.createOscillator();
var osc3 = ctx.createOscillator();
$(document).ready(function () {
    //WAVEFORM OBJECTS - used to set the value of "cur_wave_osc" under Waveform sliders.//
    var wF = {
        0: "Sine",
        1: "Square",
        2: "Sawtooth",
        3: "Triangle"
    };
    //PLAY_PAUSE BUTTONS - used to play & pause the oscillators.//
    //OSC1 PLAY_PAUSE//
    $('#play_pause_osc1').click(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "Play Osc1") {
            $(this).val("Pause");
            oscillator1Start();
        } else {
            $(this).val("Play Osc1");
            osc1.disconnect();
        }
    });
    //OSC2 PLAY_PAUSE//
    $('#play_pause_osc2').click(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "Play Osc2") {
            $(this).val("Pause");
            oscillator2Start();
        } else {
            $(this).val("Play Osc2");
            osc2.disconnect();
        }
    });
    //OSC3 PLAY_PAUSE//
    $('#play_pause_osc3').click(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "Play Osc3") {
            $(this).val("Pause");
            oscillator3Start();
        } else {
            $(this).val("Play Osc3");
            osc3.disconnect();
        }
    });
    //GAIN SLIDERS - used for controlling osc volume.//
    //OSC1_GAIN//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc1_vol").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 1,
            value: 0.5,
            step: 0.01,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_vol_osc1").val(ui.value);
                gainNode1.gain.value = $("#cur_vol_osc1").val();
            }
        });
        $("#cur_vol_osc1").val($("#osc1_vol").slider("value"));
    });
    //OSC2_GAIN//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc2_vol").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 1,
            value: 0.5,
            step: 0.01,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_vol_osc2").val(ui.value);
                gainNode2.gain.value = $("#cur_vol_osc2").val();
            }
        });
        $("#cur_vol_osc2").val($("#osc2_vol").slider("value"));
    });
    //OSC3_GAIN//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc3_vol").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 1,
            value: 0.5,
            step: 0.01,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_vol_osc3").val(ui.value);
                gainNode3.gain.value = $("#cur_vol_osc3").val();
            }
        });
        $("#cur_vol_osc3").val($("#osc3_vol").slider("value"));
    });
    //PITCH SLIDERS - used for controlling osc pitch.//
    //OSC1_PITCH//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc1_pitch").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 25000,
            value: 440,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_pitch_osc1").val(ui.value);
                osc1.frequency.value = $("#cur_pitch_osc1").val();
            }
        });
        $("#cur_pitch_osc1").val($("#osc1_pitch").slider("value"));
    });
    //OSC2_PITCH//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc2_pitch").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 25000,
            value: 440,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_pitch_osc2").val(ui.value);
                osc2.frequency.value = $("#cur_pitch_osc2").val();
            }
        });
        $("#cur_pitch_osc2").val($("#osc2_pitch").slider("value"));
    });
    //OSC3_PITCH//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc3_pitch").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 25000,
            value: 440,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_pitch_osc3").val(ui.value);
                osc3.frequency.value = $("#cur_pitch_osc3").val();
            }
        });
        $("#cur_pitch_osc3").val($("#osc3_pitch").slider("value"));
    });
    //DETUNE SLIDER - used for controlling osc detune.//
    //OSC1_DETUNE//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc1_detune").slider({
            min: -4800,
            max: 4800,
            value: 0,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_detune_osc1").val(ui.value);
                osc1.detune.value = $("#cur_detune_osc1").val();
            }
        });
        $("#cur_detune_osc1").val($("#osc1_detune").slider("value"));
    });
    //OSC2_DETUNE//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc2_detune").slider({
            min: -4800,
            max: 4800,
            value: 0,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_detune_osc2").val(ui.value);
                osc2.detune.value = $("#cur_detune_osc2").val();
            }
        });
        $("#cur_detune_osc2").val($("#osc2_detune").slider("value"));
    });
    //OSC3_DETUNE//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc3_detune").slider({
            min: -4800,
            max: 4800,
            value: 0,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_detune_osc3").val(ui.value);
                osc3.detune.value = $("#cur_detune_osc3").val();
            }
        });
        $("#cur_detune_osc3").val($("#osc3_detune").slider("value"));
    });
    //WAVEFORM SLIDERS - used for selecting osc waveform.//
    //OSC1_WAVEFORM//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc1_wave").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 3,
            value: 0,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_wave_osc1").val(wF[ui.value]);
            }
        });
        $("#cur_wave_osc1").val("Sine");
        osc1.type = $("#osc1_wave").slider("value");
    });
    //OSC2_WAVEFORM//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc2_wave").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 3,
            value: 0,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_wave_osc2").val(wF[ui.value]);
            }
        });
        $("#cur_wave_osc2").val("Sine");
        osc2.type = $("#osc2_wave").slider("value");
    });
    //OSC3_WAVEFORM//
    $(function () {
        $("#osc3_wave").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 3,
            value: 0,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#cur_wave_osc3").val(wF[ui.value]);
            }
        });
        $("#cur_wave_osc3").val("Sine");
        osc3.type = $("#osc3_wave").slider("value");
    });
});
//CREATE OSCILLATORS//
//OSC1//
function oscillator1Start() {
    //creates the osc
    osc1 = ctx.createOscillator();
    //sets waveform
    osc1.type = $("#osc1_wave").slider("value"); //0 = sine, 1 = square, 2 = saw, 3 = triangle, 4 = custom
    //sets frequency
    osc1.frequency.value;
    //sets detune
    osc1.detune.value;
    //creates a gain node
    gainNode1 = ctx.createGainNode();
    //connects osc to gain node
    osc1.connect(gainNode1);
    //connects gain node to speakers
    gainNode1.connect(speakers);
    //sets gain value
    gainNode1.gain.value;
    //plays the osc
    osc1.start(0);
}
//OSC2//
function oscillator2Start() {
    //creates the osc
    osc2 = ctx.createOscillator();
    //sets waveform
    osc2.type; //0 = sine, 1 = square, 2 = saw, 3 = triangle, 4 = custom
    //sets frequency
    osc2.frequency.value;
    //sets detune
    osc2.detune.value;
    //creates a gain node
    gainNode2 = ctx.createGainNode();
    //connects osc to gain node
    osc2.connect(gainNode2);
    //connects gain node to speakers
    gainNode2.connect(speakers);
    //sets gain value
    gainNode2.gain.value;
    //plays the osc
    osc2.start(0);
}
//OSC3//
function oscillator3Start() {
    //creates the osc
    osc3 = ctx.createOscillator();
    //sets waveform
    osc3.type; //0 = sine, 1 = square, 2 = saw, 3 = triangle, 4 = custom
    //sets frequency
    osc3.frequency.value;
    //sets detune
    osc3.detune.value;
    //creates a gain node
    gainNode3 = ctx.createGainNode();
    //connects osc to gain node
    osc3.connect(gainNode3);
    //connects gain node to speakers
    gainNode3.connect(speakers);
    //sets gain value
    gainNode3.gain.value;
    //plays the osc
    osc3.start(0);
}
```

it seems like I have a lot of repetitive code so I was considering making some constructors for things like creating a a new osc or play/pause button. The problem I'm running into though, is since my oscillator controls are controlled via jquery how would i still use my jQuery sliders, buttons in the constructors?

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
var ctx = new webkitAudioContext();
//object constructor
function Osc(type,freq,detune,gain)
{
    this.create = new ctx.createOscillator();
    this.type = type; //0 = sine, 1 = square, 2 = saw, 3 = triangle, 4 = custom
    this.freq = freq;
    this.detune = detune;
    this.gain = gain;
    this.changeType = changeType;
    function changeType(type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    };
    this.changeFreq = changeFreq;
    function changeFreq(freq)
    {
        this.freq = freq;
    };
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I just picked one part of the code that could use some polishing. Consider the following :

```
$('#play_pause_osc1').click(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "Play Osc1") {
        $(this).val("Pause");
        oscillator1Start();
    } else {
        $(this).val("Play Osc1");
        osc1.disconnect();
    }
});
```

You are switching here from one label back to another in a cycle, and then also do something. You do this for a ton of click listeners. You could do something like

```
function switchButton( $button, label1, label2, function1, function2 )
{
  if( $button.val() == label1 )
  {
    $(this).val( label2 );
    function1();   
  }
  else
  {
    $(this).val( label1 );
    function2();   
  }
}

$('#play_pause_osc1').click( function() 
{ 
  switchButton( "Play Osc1" , "Pause" , oscillator1Start ,  osc1.disconnect );
});
$('#play_pause_osc2').click( function() 
{
  switchButton( "Play Osc2" , "Pause" , oscillator2Start ,  osc2.disconnect );
});
$('#play_pause_osc3').click( function() 
{
  switchButton( "Play Osc3" , "Pause" , oscillator3Start ,  osc3.disconnect );
});
```

This is much less code, but it is obvious that you still have copy pasted code. It is also obvious that your oscillators should be in an array.

On a final note, are you sure your code is working ? The following statements do completely nothing, and they are part of your `oscillatornStart`:

```
   //sets frequency
   osc1.frequency.value;
   //sets detune
   osc1.detune.value;
   //sets gain value
   gainNode1.gain.value;
```